# Incorrect default value passed to the SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have set my column to int not null default 1... but whenever I save my record, it sets default value for that record to be 0.

I am not setting it anywhere. I don't know where I am making a mistake.

I have debugged my code , and when I am passing new entity object it is setting default value for not null to 0 .May be it is something with LINQ, But I don't know how to handle it.I don't want to explicitly assign value.
Thanks!

Comment: You'd post what you've tried so far.

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Emp] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Emp_DOJ  DEFAULT (GETDATE())  FOR [DOJ]

Comment: Please check the table script again

Comment: @Azar I Have Checked Design Of My Table And Default Value IS Set To 1 There.

Comment: @SinghKailash I Added Constraint Exactly The Same Way You Mentioned With The GetDate replaced With 1 .

Comment: @Thangadurai.B I Tried Changing My Column To Nullable But That Too Raised Issues.I Never Faced Such An Issue With Default Value.

Answer (score 0):

For sql-server, you can use *SQL Server Profiler* to catch all the scripts you run into the DB.
This may show you some details

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query, replacing the `'myTable'` and `'myColumn'` values with your actual `TABLE` and `COLUMN` names, and see what's returned:

```
SELECT
     OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) AS [Table Name]
    ,C.Name AS [Column Name]
    ,DC.Name AS [Constraint Name]
    ,DC.Type_Desc AS [Constraint Type]
    ,DC.Definition AS [Default Value]
FROM sys.default_constraints DC
INNER JOIN sys.Columns C
    ON DC.parent_column_id = C.column_id
    AND DC.parent_object_id = C.object_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(DC.parent_object_id) = 'myTable'
AND COL_NAME(DC.parent_object_id,DC.parent_column_id) = 'myColumn'
;
```

Should return something like this:

```
[Table Name]    [Column Name]   [Constraint Name]    [Constraint Type]     [Default Value]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myTable         myColumn        DF_myTable_myColumn  DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT     ('0')
```

If the `[Default Value]` returned is indeed `(1)`, then it means that you have set the constraint properly and something else is at play here.  It might be a trigger, or some other automated DML that you've forgotten/didn't know about, or something else entirely.

I am not the world's biggest fan of using a `TRIGGER`, but in a case like this, it could be handy.  I find that one of the best uses for a `TRIGGER` is debugging little stuff like this - because it lets you see what values are being passed into a table without having to scroll through mountains of profiler data. You could try something like this (again, switching out the `myTable` and `myColumn` values with your actual table and column names):

```
CREATE TABLE Default_Check 
(
     Action_Time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,Inserted_Value INT
);

CREATE TRIGGER Checking_Default ON myTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Default_Check (Inserted_Value)
    SELECT I.myColumn
    FROM Inserted I
    ;
END
;
```

This trigger would simply list the date/time of an update/insert done against your table, as well as the inserted value.  After creating this, you could run a single `INSERT` statement, then check:

```
SELECT * FROM Default_Check;
```

If you see one row, only one action (insert/update) was done against the table.  If you see two, something you don't expect is happening - you can check to see what.  You will also see here when the `0` was inserted/updated.

When you're done, just make sure you `DROP` the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER Checking_Default;
```

You'll want to `DROP` the table, too, once it's become irrelevant:

```
DROP TABLE Default_Check;
```

If all of this still didn't help you, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> In VB use
>
> **Property VariableName As Integer? = Nothing**

And

> In C# use
>
> **int? value = 0;**
>
> **if (value == 0)**
> **{**
> **value = null;**
> **}**

Answer (score 0):

```html
Please check  My Example: 

create table emp ( ids int null, [DOJ] datetime NOT null)
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Emp] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Emp_DOJ DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [DOJ] 

 1--Not working for Default Values
 insert into emp
 select '1',''

2 ---working for Default Values
 insert into emp(ids) Values(13)

 select * From emp
```

Comment: @Umara  try Like  insert into emp(ids) Values(13)